# How to handle an Excel file after data exported to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have 1000's of Excel files, and the data stored in them needs to be imported into SQL Server. The minimum size of 250 kb to 50mb.

Currently, I am storing the files in the server location and importing each file content to SQL Server. Once the data imported, the physical file still remains in the system for future reference.

But now the file occupies more than 25Gb of our server space. I don't want to delete the source files.

Can anyone help me sort out this problem?

I'm planning to convert the source file into bytes and store those bytes in SQL Server. But I don't know it is the right way of handling it.

Comment: How about adding extra SSD drive?

Comment: In SQL Server or on a drive it will use the same amount of space. Why not backup them using you backup solution and then delete?

Comment: What about using AWS Glacier? https://aws.amazon.com/es/glacier/

Answer (score 1):

CSV is the best way for keep your files .You should try convert your .xls to .csv ...That happend to me and I resolved with this method.